# Best way to define number is unsigned char in c++

Tags: c++, types

I had some code that when simplified is essentially this

```
unsigned char a=255;
unsigned char b=0;
while (a+1==b) {//do something}
```

Now since 255+1=0 with unsigned chars I was expecting it to do something but it didn't because it promoted everything to int.  I can make it work by replacing `a+1` with either `(unsigned char)(a+1)` or `(a+1)%256`.

What would be the best way to tell the compiler that I don't want the types to be changed?  Or should I just be doing 1 of the ways I know works?

Comment: Why not increment it?

Comment: Terminology note: Nothing was typecast. Some promotions took place.

Comment: Have you checked your compiler's assembly?

Comment: unless you say otherwise arithmetic will be done using the largest type in an expression, 1 is an int, so everything is promoted to int. If you tried to store it back into an `unsigned char` then you would see interesting behavior

Comment: Sometimes you'll see code that looks like `(a+1) &0xFF`, but any compiler worth a darn these days should see `(a+1)%256` and and generate pretty much the exact same output.

Comment: Use C++-style casts instead of C-style cast, eg: `static_cast<unsigned char>(a+1) `

Comment: @zdf because that value is not supose to be modified by the function.  Another thread modifies it.

Comment: @user4581301 good point that a & operator is faster then mod operator and has the same result.

Comment: @pm100 other then defining a constant is there any way to say the 1 should be unsigned char?

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse *"because that value is not supose to be modified by the function. Another thread modifies it."* If a thread is modifying a `unsigned char` while another is trying to read from it, you have Undefined Behavior (unless you have synchronization that you omitted from the code provided). One likely result of this is the reading thread might never actually see any changes to `a`.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes very valid and I will need to make sure to handle that in real situation.  This was a simplification to show just the part of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [This cppreference.com page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion), "arithmetic operators don't accept types smaller than int as arguments."  That said, your proposed solution of `(unsigned char)(a + 1)` is enough to keep this promotion from happening and `a` will roll over to 0. Using the modulo operator is more explicit but it introduces an additional operation in the machine code. It's a balance between clarity and performance.